# Prevent site description to appear on Facebook "shared link" post through API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

*All the related topics i found by looking around explain how to control the description that facebook adds to shared link, but that doesn't address my problem.*

---

### In short

**I want no description to appear in the frame of a shared link.**

---

### In details

I use the API to automatically share a link on a community page:

```
facebook->api('/'.sfConfig::get('app_facebook_page_id').'/feed', 'post', $params)
// $params holds 'name', 'caption', 'picture' and 'link' entries (no 'message')
```

I get a post on Facebook with no message, and the link frame, but under the caption, there is the target website's description.

All i want is to prevent this site's description to appear, because my "caption" already says all the necessary things. And of course, i need to keep the description tag on my website's pages.

Thank you by advance for anyone with a clue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to pass a space as the description parameter and Facebook will overwrite the Open Graph value.

My example is in JS, not PHP, hope that's ok:

```
$('#post').click(function() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        $.post(
            'https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=' + response.authResponse.accessToken,
            {
                link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/#checktoken',
                description: ' '
            },
            function (data) { console.log(data); }
        );
    });
});
```

The above code is working for me, it clears the description off the post:

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]